# Using Timeit within a while loop and increasing input size

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm stumped. Basically, I have two functions that take an input (which is a list of randomly generated numbers).

Then I wanted to figure out the size of the input list in which the time it takes both functions to execute is equal.

Here's what I have:

```
def function1(inputlist):
    #does something to inputlist

def function2(inputlist):
    #does same thing to inputlist as before but in different way

time1 = timeit.timeit(stmt="function1(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000), 10)",setup = "from file import function1,input",number=100)

time2 = timeit.timeit(stmt="function2(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000), 10)",setup = "from file import function2,input",number=100)

i=0
while time1<time2:
    time1 = timeit.timeit(stmt="function1(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000), i)",setup = "from file import function1",number=100)

    time2 = timeit.timeit(stmt="function2(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000), i)",setup = "from file import function2",number=100)

    i = i+1

print(i)
```

I can't figure this out. I've tried everything I could find. I know you can't reference outside variables when using `timeit`, so I tried working around that too. I basically need any sort of method where I can increase the input side of the function and calculate each time.

Thanks so much in advance. I've been struggling on this for over a day now.

Comment: Why not just substitute `i` into the string? Via `.format`, `%`, or f-strings?

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not sure how to go about that. How would I incorporate this? Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way here, would be to format the string accordingly:

Instead of

```
stmt="function1(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000)], i))"
```

write

```
stmt=f"function1(random.sample([x for x in range(0, 20000)], {i}))"
```

This will put the current value of `i` where `{i}` stands. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) for further information.